# Search Informatica for text in SQL override

Tags: informatica

Is there a way to search all the mappings, sessions, etc. in Informatica for a text string contained within a SQL override?

For example, suppose I know a certain stored procedure (`SP_FOO`) is being called somewhere in an INFA process, but I don't know where exactly.  Somewhere I think there is a Post SQL on a source or target calling it.  Could I search all the sessions for Post SQL containing `SP_FOO` ?  (Similar to what I could do with `grep` with source code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Repository queries for querying REPO tables(if you have enough access) to get data related with all the mappings,transformations,sessions etc.

Please use the below link to get almost all kind of repo queries.Ur answers can be find in the below link.

https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/display/EDW/Querying+PowerCenter+data

```
select *--distinct sbj.SUBJECT_AREA,m.PARENT_MAPPING_NAME
from REP_SUBJECT sbj,REP_ALL_MAPPINGS m,REP_WIDGET_INST w,REP_WIDGET_ATTR wa
where sbj.SUBJECT_ID = m.SUBJECT_ID AND
m.MAPPING_ID = w.MAPPING_ID AND
w.WIDGET_ID = wa.WIDGET_ID
and sbj.SUBJECT_AREA in ('TLR','PPM_PNLST_WEB','PPM_CURRENCY','OLA','ODS','MMS','IT_METRIC','E_CONSENT','EDW','EDD','EDC','ABS')
and (UPPER(ATTR_VALUE)  like '%PSA_CONTACT_EVENT%'
--  or UPPER(ATTR_VALUE)  like '%PSA_MEMBER_CHARACTERISTIC%'
 -- or UPPER(ATTR_VALUE)  like '%PSA_REPORTING_HH_CHRSTC%'
--  or UPPER(ATTR_VALUE)  like '%PSA_REPORTING_MEMBER_CHRSTC%'
     )
--and m.PARENT_MAPPING_NAME like '%ARM%'
order by 1
```

Please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: The link provided is behind an log on required wall.

Answer (score 2):

Another less scientific way to do this is to export the workflow(s) as XML and use a text editor to search through them for the stored procedure name.

Answer (score 2):

If you have read access to the schema where the informatica repository resides, try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.subj_name folder, e.mapping_name, object_type_name,
                b.instance_name, a.attr_value
           FROM opb_widget_attr a,
                opb_widget_inst b,
                opb_object_type c,
                opb_attr d,
                opb_mapping e,
                opb_subject f
          WHERE a.widget_id = b.widget_id
            AND b.widget_type = c.object_type_id
            AND (   object_type_name = 'Source Qualifier'
                 OR object_type_name LIKE '%Lookup%'
                )
            AND a.widget_id = b.widget_id
            AND a.attr_id = d.attr_id
            AND c.object_type_id = d.object_type_id
            AND attr_name IN ('Sql Query')--, 'Lookup Sql Override')
            AND b.mapping_id = e.mapping_id
            AND e.subject_id = f.subj_id
            AND a.attr_value is not null
            --AND UPPER (a.attr_value) LIKE UPPER ('%currency%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a small java based tool called Informatica Meta Query.

Using that tool, you can search for any information that is present in the Informatica meta data tables.

If you cannot find that tool, you can write queries directly in the Informatica Meta data tables to get the required information.

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more lines to  solution provided by Data Origin and Sandeep.

It is highly advised not to query repository tables directly. Rather, you can create synonyms or views and then query those objects to avoid any damage to rep tables.
In our dev/ prod environment application programmers are not granted any direct access to repo. tables.

Answer (score 0):

As querying the Informatica database isn't the best idea, I would suggest you to export all the workflows in your folder into xml using Repository Manager. From Rep Mgr you can select all of them once and export them at once. Then write a java program to search the pattern from the xml's you have.

I have written a sample prog here, please modify it as per your requirement:
make a spec file with workflow names(specFileName).

```
main()
{ 
    try {
        File inFile = new File(specFileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newFileReader(infile));

        String tectToSearch = '<YourString>';
        String currentLine;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //trim newline when comparing with String
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            if(currentline has the string pattern)
            {
             SOP(specFileName); //specfile name
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading to file '" + specFileName +"'");

    }
}
```